# Can you use data binding on class objects?

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to data bind some text boxes to show various fields of a class I made:

I tried the following code.

```
    MyClass ClassObj = new MyClass();
    DataContext = ClassObj;

    // Create a new binding
    // Val1 is a variable of type String in MyClass class
    Binding myNewBindDef = new Binding("Val1");

    myNewBindDef.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    myNewBindDef.Source = ClassObj;

    // txtBox1is a TextBlock object that is the binding target object
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(txtBox1, TextBox.TextProperty, myNewBindDef);
```

I've added a using 
for System.Windows.Data and System.ComponentModel, and MyClass implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  However the text box is empty when I run the app and updating the value of ClassObj.Val1 does not affect anything.

What steps am I missing, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, turns out I had to make Val1 a public variable first

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to INotifyPropertyChanged would be to make MyClass inherit from DependencyObject and create a DependencyProperty for Val1 using the DependencyProperty.Register() function.  The DependencyProperty should be stored in a public level static member of MyClass.  Then in the getter and setter for the Val1 property use GetValue() and SetValue() to access the DependencyProperty.